# What's the difference among "lights went out" , "lights went off" and "lights went down"?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I'm just a beginner. So, I'm sorry for my bad English. I bumped into a question on Instagram onto a page created for people who want to improve their English skills. The question was " All the lights in the building suddenly went...? A) off B) out C) down " The correct answer was A but I didn't get it. So I was just wondering what is the difference between went out went off and went down.

Comment: "went" is the past simple tense of *go*, so look up the meaning of "go off/out/down“ in any online dictionary. Try Lexico or Merriam-Webster

Comment: Lights go off or out. Computers go down.

Comment: @KateBunting, the lights can "go down" in a theater, before the start of a movie or play.

Comment: @whiskeychief Very true - I hadn't thought of that one.

Comment: I'd say the test is wrong. "off" and "out" are both correct. In fact, I think "out" is even a little better. "The lights went off" is what you would expect to happen when you flip the switch at the end of a work day, for instance, but if "the lights went out", we have no idea why, and the test question included "surprising", so I'd have chosen "out"

Comment: The question is a poor one, because any of the three options could be correct, depending on additional context. If anything I would facvor "out" as suggested in the comment by gotube and the answer by Ethan Bolker

Answer (score 3):

Lights go off when people (or timers) make that happen using a switch.

Lights go out when there is a power failure or other accident.

Lights go down when they dim. That happens in a theater when the play is about to start.

To me, in your question, the "suddenly" suggests a power failure. The lights went out. I would choose (B).

Answer (score 0):

I think using "went off" is related to "turn off lights", which means the light is turned off.